# hibernate extra column with custom query(subquery)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer count;
```

I want to assign to

> count

count = `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people`

How to assign result:`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people`  to Integer count using JpaRepository?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@Formula` helps you create for your own formulas in `Hibernate`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @Formula("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people)")  // people is table name not entity
    private Integer count;
```

Comment: Is it possible to add condition in Formula? like:  @Formula("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people where group = :groupId)")